# Case statements around values in a list

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table that looks like below after performing certain joins:

```
create table test(id varchar(10), sub varchar(20));

insert into test values(1,'a')
insert into test values(1,'b')
insert into test values(2,'a')
insert into test values(3,'a')
insert into test values(3,'c')
```

I want see what values a particular id has in sub column and output as following (expected results):

```
1,'both a and b'
2,'only a'
3,'both a and c'
```

I tried the following:

```
select id, case when sub in ('a') then 'only a'
when sub in ('a','b') then 'both a and b')
else 'only b'
end as subs from test group by 1,2;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current select attempt.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: **never**, ever store numbers in a `varchar` column (like you do with column `id`)

Comment: Vertica @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select id, (case when max(sub) = min(sub) and min(sub) = 'a' 
                 then 'only a'
                 when max(sub) = min(sub) and min(sub) = 'b'  
                 then 'only b'
                 when max(sub) <> min(sub)
                 then 'both a and b' 
            end)
from test t
where t.sub in ('a', 'b')
group by id;
```

**EDIT :** Removed `where` clause & do concat.

```
select id, (case when max(sub) = min(sub) 
                 then 'only' || min(sub)
                 when max(sub) <> min(sub)
                 then 'multiple'
            end)
from test t
group by id;
```

Comment: What if another sub is added say c, and now we want see if a and c or b and c?

Answer (score 0):

for sql server:

You can use, it will list the sub it has by id

```
select distinct id ,
STUFF((Select ','+sub
from #test T1
where T1.id=T2.id
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') from #test T2
where id = 3
```

For postgres, use

```
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG (sub) as sugagg
from #test T1
GROUP BY
    id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self-join:

```
SELECT 
    ta.id, 
    CASE WHEN ta.id is NULL THEN
        CASE WHEN tb.id IS NULL then 'neither' ELSE '"b" only'
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN tb.id IS NULL then '"a" only' ELSE '"a" and "b"'
    END AS summary
FROM test ta
FULL OUTER JOIN test tb
ON ta.id = tb.id AND tb.sub = 'b'
WHERE ta.sub='a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use sql server  try this Solution

```
SELECT 
   SS.id,
   STUFF((SELECT 'and' + SS.sub
          FROM test ts 
          WHERE ts.id = SS.id
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [sub]
FROM test SS
GROUP BY SS.id
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd results.  I would rather have the full list.  But in any case:

```
select id,
       (case when max(sub) = min(sub) 
             then 'only ' || min(sub)
             when count(distinct sub) = 2
             then 'both ' || min(sub) || ' and ' || max(sub)
             else 'I don''t have that many fingers.
        end)
from test t
group by id;
```

If you want the full list, use [`listagg()`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm):

```
select id, listagg(distinct sub, ',') within group (order by sub)
from test t
group by id;
```